# How to use Susy Sass with Masonry layout?

Tags: jquery, sass, susy-sass

i am using Susy gallery mixin, or i could just use span, and the height of the items is not equal. So i must use Masonry as well, but it messes my layout always.

Sass:

```
.item { @include span(3); }
```

Javascript

```
var msnry = new Masonry( 'div.home', {
    itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

Has anyone done that before?

This is the masonry script i am using: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue a little while back. If you check the [masonry docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth) you should see the option to pass an element selector as the columnWidth setting to masonry. Using this you can have susy tell masonry the widths of your elements. One thing I struggled with though was using gutters. In the end I resorted to using susy's inside-static method and used inner elements to provide styling.

I've put together a [basic codepen](http://codepen.io/jackw/pen/ZYVgwq) that should help explain things. Below is the scss for reference.

```
@import "susy";

//
// Converts a px value to EMs
// @param  {number} $px    px value to convert to EMs
// @param  {number} $base  The base pixel value to divide by. Defaults to $base-font-size
// @return {number}        returns em value
//
@function toEm($px, $base: $base-font-size) {
    @return ($px / $base) * 1em;
}


$base-font-size: 13px;

$susy : layout(12 (toEm(70px) toEm(20px)) inside-static ) !global;

@include border-box-sizing;

.container {
  @include container;
  font-size: $base-font-size;
}

// A gutterless item.
.item {
  @include border-radius(5px);
  @include span(3);
  background: #d26;
  border: 2px solid rgba(#333,0.25);
  height: 40px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}

// an item with gutters should have styling placed in .inner elements
.item-gutter {
  @include span(3);
  margin-bottom: gutter();
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
  margin-top: gutter();
}

.item-gutter .inner {
  @include border-radius(5px);
  background: #d26;
  border: 2px solid rgba(#333,0.25);
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
}

.item.w2,
.item-gutter.w2 {
  width: span(6);
}

.item.w3,
.item-gutter.w3 {
  width: span(9);
}

.item.h2,
.item-gutter.h2 .inner {
  height: 80px;
}
.item.h3,
.item-gutter.h3 .inner {
  height: 120px;
}

// this element is used by masonry to understand the width of a single column
.grid-sizer {
  width: span(3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i gave up on Masonry. It got too messy. Instead i hooked up with Salvattore! https://github.com/keevitaja/susy-and-salvattore-masonry